# Is it okay calling Lua function from different thread(embedding Lua in C++)?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm using VS2008, lua 5.1 and luabind 0.9.1.

Calling Lua function from C++ works just fine.

If there're several threads and **Lua function is invoked from each thread**, has this situation  any problem? There is only **ONE** Lua state.

In that situation, should I have more Lua state? Which one is common?

Comment: A couple of quick Google searches seems to indicate that the Lua VM is not thread safe, so I would recommend to use one state per thread.

Comment: But, what if it just invokes Lua function? Calling Lua function can change its state?

Comment: I'm guessing all VM registers and the call-stack and other important variables are stored in the state, which is a source of disaster if two threads uses the state at the same time. Either protect the calling of Lua functions with e.g. a mutex, or use different states.

Answer (score 5):

That's not OK just like that. The Lua users wiki has a nice [page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial) about threading.

Comment: Especially noteworthy in this case is the section *Locking by Lua* in the wiki. Note that this in essence is a [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) and if you do a lot of processing in the threads, you end up with pretty-much serial code...